# Can't create HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd

I am trying to create a simple window, but I had some problem. Compiler won't give error, but it simply can't create the hWnd of the window. Also it says that "msg" variable is being used without being initialized. It is not an error, just a warning, however I feel uncomfortable. It says "unused    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated" when I click to the hWnd table in the debug screen. Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Breakout_Test";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "Breakout_Test", "Breakout Test (DirectX 9)", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
                            0, 0, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using PeekMessage instead of GetMessage? The reason for the warning is that you're checking msg.message before msg is ever initialized.

Comment: Because, I wanted to write a DirectX application. And in DirectX applications(like games etc.), programmers suggest to use PeekMessage, instead of GetMessage. I wanted to try to compile the code, but when I compiled it, i won't create a window. I get uncomfortable because of that, and wrote the problem in here. Maybe PeekMessage only works when I write the DirectX rendering, initializing codes etc. And I don't know when msg is ever initialized. How I can know?

Comment: You can know that `msg` is not initialised, because it's clearly so in the code. You test the value of `msg.message` before ever assigning anything to `msg.message`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your message loop is all wrong. The compiler is quite right that you are not initializing `msg`. I'm not sure where you got that message loop from. Here's the standard one:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

If you want to use a non-blocking `PeekMessage` based loop which seems popular for DirectX applications, it might look like this:

```
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) 
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        // game code here
    }
}
```

Notice that we initialise `msg` before entering the `while` loop which tests `msg.message`.

Your other big problem is in your window procedure. You don't return the value that you get back from `DefWindowProc`. The `default` handler should look like this:

```
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Your broken window procedure is the reason why `CreateWindowEx` fails. A broken window procedure is one of the classic failure modes for `CreateWindowEx`.

Make these two changes and your program will work.

---

For people like Remy, who are worried about the fact that [`GetMessage` returns `-1` when it fails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx), [Raymond Chen explains why you don't need to worry about that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx), at least for this message loop.

Comment: You need to use `while (GetMessage(...) > 0)` instead. [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx), this is very clearly described in detail in the **Return value** section.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx

Comment: OK, it worked thanks. I used PeekMessage, because I was actually writing a DirectX application, and I think we should use PeekMessage instad of it when writing a DirectX app. I didn't wrote the DirectX renderer, initializer codes etc. I just wanted to see if it is working, and when I see it doesn't work, i get worried. And how can we find out when is msg initialized? Whatever, I wanted to ask one more thing. You said we should use DefWindowProc as a return value, but in this site: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html It is used in default value, and the program runs perfectly?

Comment: No, the page you link to has `return DefWindowProc(...)`, but you wrote `DefWindowProc(...)`.

Comment: Oh, OK I'm learning so much thing, thanks. The site says, don't write things like "thanks" etc. but I can't resist to say thanks, because you helped me very much. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The uninitialized variable is indeed a warning, and you *should* feel uncomfortable, because the warning is correct. You check whether `msg.message` is `WM_QUIT` before you've assigned anything to `msg`.

You'll have to do more debugging to find out about the failure to create a window handle; the question doesn't include any information about that — not even an indication that such a problem is being *checked* for.

The inability to inspect the variable in the debugger could be due to the optimizer removing information about it after it's no longer used. Once `ShowWindow` returns, there's no need to maintain the `hWnd` variable. Continue using it in your code, and you might see it live longer in the debugger.

Comment: That's not how an optimizer works. The variable is either evicted completely, or visible in the entire scope. A `HWND` however does not have any useful information anyway, it's just an index into a private table. Trying to expand it in the debugger will yield `unused | <Unable to read memory>`, even for a valid `HWND`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Should be:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

The default should be:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

Also, I am not sure if this would make a difference, but I think it would:
When you define `msg` it should be:

```
MSG msg = { };
```

or

```
MSG msg = {0};
```

Comment: No need to do like this. It won't warn me for the msg anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `default` clause is wrong. While it does call `DefWindowProc` it fails to pass its return value back. One of the first messages sent to your `WndProc` is [`WM_NCCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632635.aspx). Since you unconditionally `return 0;` (aka `FALSE`) window creation stops and `CreateWindowEx` returns NULL.

Comment: Oh, this explains why I can't create the HWND, thanks really much. It was really explaining.